# Xcode IOS Webview not loading

Tags: ios, xcode, url, webview, uibutton

I have a UIButton in one view that gets tapped and should load a Url in a webView.
Here is the code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.webView.delegate = self;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];
    NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:requestURL];
}
```

Here is the error:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[WebView initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Haven't you set by mistake class like `WebView` in storyboard? And do you have that class in your project?

Comment: Hi Azat, i do have a class named WebView in my project.

Comment: If you used storyboards, please select the webView in the story board and on the inspector check what class it's set to? (ps storyboards are so ugly, everything should be done programmatically)

Comment: Is `WebView` a subclass of `UIWebView`?

Comment: WebView is subclass of UIViewcontroller

Comment: Ahh Yes I see. There was a mistake with the classes. thanks!